# Objective-C iOS app not storing data in array of objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, appdelegate

this is a very hard question to ask because I don't want to flood you with all of my code, being that most of it is not pertinent to the problem. So I won't be to surprised if this goes unanswered. Although, it could be something hella simple that I am missing haha. Here it goes:

So my app is storing an array via [encoder] in my appDelegate. The app is full of objects that are creates in a separate NSObject class. Think of it this way for examples sake:
I have my main viewController class. And in appDelegate I define/encode an array of objects.
Now in my main, I fill the array with 10 "cars". My car class has variables such as color, make, model, etc.. Now when I save and relaunch the app, the array that I have saved is now an array containing 10 elements, but it seems to have forgotten all of the variables for each instance of the car class.

When I relaunch the app, If I call NSLog(@"%@",array in appDelegate); It prints 10 lines that look a lot like this:
""
So I know the array is being stored with 10 elements, and 10 elements are saved, but like i said, all of the variables are gone.

Note: On the first run of the app, and the array is being filled for the first time, I can access all the variables perfectly, and nothing is wrong.

Thank you for any help that I can get!!

Comment: Please post the code for your implementation of initWithCoder and encodeWithCoder on the "car" class. If you haven't implemented them, that's your problem.

Comment: haha yes, that was my problem. I saw it soon after posting. I have already been saving a string from a different class, and completely forgot aboutinitWithCode/encodeWithCoder hahaha. Thank you! 
Post what you said as a solution and I will mark it as answered.

Comment: Thanks, I added a bit more detail to help future readers too :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to see the code for your implementation of initWithCoder and encodeWithCoder on the "car" class. If you haven't implemented them, that's your problem.

What is probably happening currently is that only the superclass implementation of these methods is being invoked. This means the correct class will be recreated but no data will be saved or restored.

[NSCoding protocol reference doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your main class as well as all the objects you put into the array all need to conform to NSCoding. If the objects in the array aren't NSCoding compliant, they won't get coded automatically.